# How can I get the value of a selected dropdown before posting the page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<?php 

$options = array(
                  500  => 500,
                  1000 => 1000,
                  2500 => 2500,
                  5000 => 5000,
                );

echo form_dropdown('units',$options);

?>

$db_num = 25; # a random number
$post_num = $set_num * (units-selected)
```

how do i get multiply the selected value of of the units dropdown with my `$db_num` when submit is clicked? I think this may need javascript but is it possible without?

On my controller I tried this:

```
$db_num = $this->input->post('db_num');
$units = $this->input->post('units');

$answer = $db_num * $units;

...

echo $answer;
```

(result is no error and no insert. What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: Why don't you just multiply in your controller?

Comment: thats exactly what i did.. not working. do you know how i can temp disable the forbidden direct access for pages in codeigniter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeigniter so forgive me if this answer is wrong, but you may need to cast the results to an int: `$answer = (int)$db_num * (int)$units;`

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?  What happens if you try to var_dump `$db_num` and `$units` in your controller?  If you have a separate question (which appears to be completely unrelated), please make it a separate question, don't ask it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database field that was passing my variable needed to be set to `INT` - Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

something like :

```
<form ... onsubmit="return functionwhereyouwilldothemath(this)" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function functionwhereyouwilldothemath(el) { //el = javascript form object
    var db_num = <?=$db_num?>; //yup this is legit.
     //do your math
    return true; //will cause the page to reload uppon submit.
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use php implode function to store and explode function to display

$itm= $_POST['hospital_department'];
                $comma_separated = implode("-", $itm);

```
$data['hospital_department']            = $comma_separated;
```